# foo() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class test:
    def foo(self, pic_path, enc_path, key_path):
        return pic_path, enc_path, key_path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = test()
    pic_path = "pic.png"
    key_path = "keys.txt"

    s.foo(pic_path, key_path)
    print("done")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.foo(pic_path, key_path)
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key_path'
```

Why? I do not understand why this does not work, what is my mistake?

Comment: Do you remember that `enc_path` parameter you said `foo` needs when you defined it?

Comment: They did provide `enc_path`. What they forgot is the `key_path` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.foo()` takes three arguments: `pic_path`, `enc_path`, and `key_path`. You are only calling it with two arguments: `pic_path` and `key_path`. You’re missing the `enc_path` between them.

In this case, `test.foo()` doesn’t care about the names of the variables you’re passing it. It just knows that you called it with two arguments instead of three.

Answer (score 2):

Your are passing two positional arguments `pic_path` and `key_path`.

`pic_path` is interpreted as `pic_path` and `key_path` as `enc_path`.

When calling the Class you have to pass enc_path as second positional argument. Or you could pass them as keyword arguments (e.g. `s.foo(enc_path = enc_path, pic_path = pic_path, key_path = key_path`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call foo with only 2 arguments, you can set foo up as such:

```
    def foo(self, pic_path, key_path, enc_path=None):
        return pic_path, enc_path, key_path
```

though you'll need to use @sp4c38's keyword arguments solution for passing them in in the first place.

(See 8.6 in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html)

EDIT: Fixed to avoid syntax error declared below.  (You could also default set them all equal to `None` though that may have side effects you don't want)

Comment: That's a SyntaxError: you can't have a non-default argument after a default argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one parameter in s.foo() call. foo function expects 3 arguments and you're passing only 2.

```
class test:
    def foo(self, pic_path, enc_path, key_path):
        return pic_path, enc_path, key_path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = test()
    pic_path = "pic.png"
    key_path = "keys.txt"
    enc_path = "asd.sc"
    s.foo(pic_path,enc_path, key_path)
    print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of `foo`, you required three parameters: `pic_path`, `enc_path`, and `key_path`, however when you are calling foo you are just passing two of them.